# How can I get async stack traces with Node and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I wish I could get stack traces to work in TypeScript. I only seem to see the bottommost function name. I'm using Node.js v12.4.0 on Windows 10 (1803).

This is the code:

```
async function thrower() {
  throw new Error("test");
}

async function level1() {
  return await thrower();
}

async function level2() {
  return await level1();
}

async function level3() {
  return await level2();
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await level3();
  } catch(err) {
    console.warn("main error", err);
  }
}

console.log("node version", process.version);

main().then(() => {
  console.log("all done " + __filename);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error("Something went wrong in here :(", __filename, err);
})
```

The resulting stack trace that does not mention `level1` or `level2` or `level3`:

```
ts-node test-stack.ts
node version v12.4.0
main error Error: test
    at D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:2:9
    at step (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:31:23)
    at Object.next (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:12:53)
    at D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:6:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:2:12)
    at thrower (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:37:12)
    at D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:6:16
    at step (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:31:23)
    at Object.next (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:12:53)
all done D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts
```

Comment: See also: [TypeScript tsconfig settings for Node.js 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59787574)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research and noticing the `__awaiter`, I decided to inspect what's TypeScript targeting. That was my problem.

Here's my bad `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "server/**/*", "tests"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

And this `"target": "es2018"` fixed it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "target": "es2018"
    },
    "include": [
        "server/**/*", "tests"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Resulting in this stack trace:

```
ts-node test-stack.ts
node version v12.4.0
main error Error: test
    at thrower (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:2:9)
    at level1 (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:6:16)
    at level2 (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:10:16)
    at level3 (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:14:16)
    at main (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:19:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts:27:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\yuv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\yuv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
all done D:\dev\server\test-stack.ts
```

Comment: Just remember to use a different production target if you have to target older environments.

Comment: Note I'm able to get the proper stack track when targeting "es2017".  This is important for my use case as using the "es2018" target seems to make the Terser plugin of Webpack very unhappy.

Comment: either this or nodejs version 16 helped. I am using `ts-node`.

Comment: @Riki137 that alone didn't add stack traces, though i tried it first. I'm not sure if it made a difference for me or if only the target of `es2018` did it.