# TypeScript tsconfig settings for Node.js 12?

Tags: node.js, typescript

What is the optimal TypeScript `tsconfig` settings for outputting code that's going to be run on Node.js 12?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

As of Node.js `12.0.0`, 100% of ES2019 is supported. If you know that you are targeting that version or newer, the optimal config would look like this:

- `"module": "commonjs"`

  Node.js is on its way to add ES-Modules, but for now we'll have to stick with CommonJS.
- `"target": "es2019"`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to output JavaScript *syntax* with features from ES2019. In practice, this means that it will e.g. output object rest/spread properties & async/await syntax instead of embedding a polyfill.
- `"lib": ["es2019", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.string", "es2020.symbol.wellknown"]`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to use *functions and properties* introduced in ES2019 or earlier. In practice, this means that you can use e.g. `String.prototype.trimStart` and `Array.prototype.flat`.

  In addition to ES2019, Node.js 12 also supports `BigInt` & `matchAll` from ES2020, therefor we include the additional definitions from ES2020.

The full config would thus be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2019", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.string", "es2020.symbol.wellknown"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019"
  }
}
```

---

**If you are targeting Node.js `12.9.0` or newer**, you can simply specify `"lib": ["es2020"]` as that version supports all new *functions and properties* introduced in ES2020. It doesn't support the new JavaScript *syntax* though, so you still have to stay on `"target": "es2019"`.

The full config would thus be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019"
  }
}
```

---

If you are running Node.js 18 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 18 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72380008/148072)

If you are running Node.js 16 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 16 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371788/148072)

If you are running Node.js 14 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 14 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/148072)

If you are running Node.js 10 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 10 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607634/148072)

If you are running Node.js 8 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466512/148072)

Comment: Does `"target"` affect `"lib"` in any way if `"lib"` is left empty in the config? If I just have `"target": "es2020"` what does `"lib"` default to? This has always been a source of mystery to me.

Comment: @Sumomo this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987516/148072) provides a little bit of insight. Although I haven't found any more info on what newer than "ES6" provides for default lib...

Comment: There is also [es2020.promise](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2020.promise.d.ts) there now which is supported starting from Node 12.10.0.

Comment: @IvanYarych the bottom part of my answer has a section for Node.js >= 12.9.0 which includes [es2020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2020.d.ts) which in turn includes es2020.promise

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck Thank you for these, they're refreshingly straight forward. I love that you went ahead and did one for Node 14 too. As far as a "citation" for this, does the TypeScript project publish these specific target and lib values for a given version of Node?

Comment: @IAmKale Than you for those kind words! The TypeScript does not publish that information, instead I've based the answers on mostly node.green, some testing myself, and the TypeScript documentation

Comment: I run tsc command. It throws "Argument for '--lib' option must be: ...."
It's running on Node v.12.9.0. Doesn't ES current allow support? :(

Comment: @LongNguyen which version of TypeScript are you using? And what does it output where you wrote "...."?

Comment: When I use this config with Typescript `3.8.3` and node `12.13.0` and try to use bigint I get the following `tsc` error: `BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ES2020`

Comment: @PiersMacDonald hmm, that is unfortunate. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell TypeScript that nullish coalescing isn't supported, while BigInt literals are. If you set target to ES2020 TypeScript will emit `??` which isn't supported by Node... If possible, I would recommend you to upgrade to Node.js 14 which supports the full ES2020 target.

Answer (score 25):

TL:DR

TypeScript maintains a mapping of target, module and lib corresponding to the node version. You can find it here
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping

Answer (score 7):

It is much easier using [tsconfig bases](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases).

Run `npm install --save-dev @tsconfig/node12` and then in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
  // ...your configrations
}
```

There is a few tsconfig bases for different environments and the community keeps adding more.