# Importing node-fetch in node project with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fetch-api

How can I import `node-fetch` package to my node project where I use `typescript`.
I tried it in many ways... right now I am on:

```
const fetch = (...args) =>
    import("node-fetch").then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));
```

But I have 2 errors:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'.
```

and

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
```

When I change `const fetch =` to any other name like `const fetchIt =` it fixes first error but... do I really have to change that? How can I import `node-fetch` package in normal way where I can use `fetch()` method? In React I just make

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

and everything works fine... why is that so hard in `node` projects?

Comment: Have you enabled the `DOM` lib in your `tsconfig.json`? If you remove this, there shouldn't be any conflict wit the global `fetch`.

Comment: @qqilihq I just did `npx tsc --init` command so I have all default values there and I don't see any `DOM` there I think

Answer (score 18):

If you have conflicts with a global `fetch`, this suggests that you have the `DOM` lib in your `tsconfig.json` enabled, e.g.:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2021", "dom"]
  }
}
```

I would suggest **removing** this. For a NodeJS project, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787575) answer for the suggested `tsconfig.json` settings depending on the NodeJS version.

After this, you will be able to import `fetch` as you wrote in your question and assign it to a variable named `fetch`, without conflicting names:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

**Alternative solution:** If you need to work with 3rd party libs which are built with a browser focus and require a global fetch, have a look at the [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) module, which adds `fetch` as global function.

You will need to import it once so that `fetch` is available globally:

```js
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

In this case, the compiler options of your `tsconfig.json` should contain the `dom` lib.

### Update 2022-02-04

Newer NodeJS versions ship a native `fetch` API now, so above will no longer be necessary going forward. See [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/6ec225392675c92b102d3caad02ee3a157c9d1b7) and [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30161626) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

### Update:

My original post below is all true. I have been able to get it to work, however, without having to switch to ESM modules.  Here is what's working in my code (based on the third code snippet in the following post:  https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1279#issuecomment-915063354)

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func
const importDynamic = new Function('modulePath', 'return import(modulePath)');

const fetch = async (...args:any[]) => {
  const module = await importDynamic('node-fetch');
  return module.default(...args);
};
```

### Original Post:

The `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetch'` error is because you're declaring a `const fetch` variable, and then reusing the name "`fetch`" as the object-destructured parameter to the `then()` callback later in the line.

So, changing the line to read as follows clears up that error:

```js
const fetch = (...args) => import("node-fetch").then(module => module.default(...args));
```

As for the other error (`A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`), one possible way to solve this would be to actually import the correct argument types for the `fetch()` call, then substitute in the above code snippet as appropriate, like this:

```js
import { RequestInfo, RequestInit } from 'node-fetch';
const fetch = (url:RequestInfo, init?:RequestInit) => import('node-fetch').then(module => module.default(url, init));
```

Unfortunately, while that seems to satisfy the TypeScript compiler, I'm finding in my own code that the runtime still doesn't work (throws an `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM`) because my TypeScript config is currently using CommonJS modules rather than an ESM format.

See https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues?q=ERR_REQUIRE_ESM for several open issues in the node-fetch package related to this problem.

Essentially, the node-fetch maintainers are suggesting those of us using TypeScript need to convert to ESM modules, away from CommonJS (see https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1397#issuecomment-978092116 and subsequent comments).

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade or install v2. `npm install node-fetch@2 && npm install --save-dev @types/node-fetch@2.x`

> What is the point of ESM 3.x when node doesn't support it? At least
> for tsc. Maybe ts-node supports it. But tsc should be compatible with
> ts-node.

```
import { default as fetch, Headers } from 'node-fetch';
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Node 12",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["es2019"],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2019",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Note: Node 14, update tsconfig to es2020 from es2019 above & display Node 14

Also, Node 17+ fetch is built-in. So by the time ESM is supported in node, you probably won't need node-fetch.

Comment: using tsc directly to a typescript file will ignore tsconfig.json unless specified as a command line option. This can lead to < es6 errors. Running `npx tsc` or tsc in package.json script, it will honor tsconfig.json

Comment: The other option is to upgrade to deno. Which in some situations is a lot better than node 18.x. Both have fetch built-in.

Comment: ESM is supported in Node for a bit.

Comment: ESM here does not work in node 14

Comment: Sure. Your original comment said ESM is not supported. My point is this is incorrect. ESM has worked for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch), it is almost the same but works everywhere, it helped me because I was not able to run node-fetch in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

This setup worked for me:

package.json

```
{
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node --esm ./src/index.ts"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import fetch, { Headers } from 'node-fetch';
// do something
```

I was using ts-node, so notice you need to apply the `--esm` compatibility:

`ts-node --esm ./src/index.ts`